# Decode and update a JSON array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, decode

I need to update my JSON array in the file jsonData_0_123.json. I can get the data from the file and decode it, but I can't update the data in the file (in this case, the array answers)

```
$contents = file_get_contents('json_files/jsonData_0_123.json');

//Decode the JSON data into a PHP array.
$contentsDecoded = json_decode($contents, true);

//Update the decoded array
$contentsDecoded[1]["answers"] = "hello";

//Encode the array back into a JSON string.
$json = json_encode($contentsDecoded);

//Save the file.
file_put_contents('json_files/jsonData_0_123.json', $json);
```

Comment: Please explain what happens. Error messages? Can you give the output of `var_export ($contentsDecoded);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code it is updating in json file with array answers.I found problem with file permission error for (jsonData_0_123.json) writing data into it.Otherwise it's working fine.